# How to get the output from second value using sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk

I have a file with below content as example

```
cat test.log
hello
how are you?
terminating
1
2
3
terminating
1
2
```

When am using grep command to show output after terminating it is showing as below.

```
sed -n '/terminating/,$p' test.log

terminating
1
2
3
terminating
1
2
```

I want output as below

```
terminating
1
2
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -n '/terminating/{N;N;h};${g;p}' file
terminating
1
2
```

If line matches `terminating`, store it and the next two lines in hold space. Print the three lines on `$EOF`.

---

Example with a `sed`script:

```
$ cat script.sed
/terminating/{
N
N
h
}
${
g
p
}

$ sed -nf script.sed file
terminating
1
2
```

---

And for all lines after the last `terminating`:

```
$ cat file
cat test.log
hello
how are you?
terminating
1
2
3
terminating
1
2
3
4
5
6

$ cat script.sed
H
/terminating/{
h
}
${
g
p
}

$ sed -nf script.sed file
terminating
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Getting "sed : command garbled /terminating/{N;N;h};${g;p}" error if use above command :(

Comment: @user2582284 you can try to use a `sed` script, please see my example.

Comment: it is working :) ... but this is working only for two lines now i have text as below

Comment: Hi Captcha,

it is working :) ... but this is working only for two lines now i have text as below

hello
how are you?
terminating
1
2
3
terminating
1
5
6
7
8
9
10

But the command you provided is not showing as below.

Terminating
1
5
6
7
8
9
10

It is giving th otput as 

terminating
1
5

Please help on this.

Comment: Hi captcha, Is there any other way with out processing file? I mean in a single syntax of sed without putting the options in file.

Comment: @user2582284 try to put every command in an `-e` block, eg. `sed -n -e H -e /terminating/h -e '$g' -e '$p' file`. I don't know, if this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^terminating/!d;:a;$!N;/.*\n(terminating)/s//\1/;$q;ba' file
```

Unless the line begins with `terminating` discard it. Read in more lines discarding any lines that are ahead of a line beginning `terminating`. At end-of-file print out the remainder of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'H;/terminating/x;${x;p}' test.log
```

As annotated pseudocode:

```
for each line:
    append the line to the hold space     H
    if line matches /terminating/         /terminating/
       then set hold space to line        x
    on the last line:                     $
        get the hold space                x
        and print                         p
```

note: `x` actually exchanges the hold/pattern spaces.

Comment: Hi, When am using above command it is throughing output as "unrecognized command : H;/terminating/x;${x;p}' ". I tried with both upper and lower cases of X and got the same output

Comment: What is your platform? sed version?